# Viewstate destroyed after Session timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms, viewstate

```
       protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister 
   {
       get
       {
           if (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(this.Page.Request.FilePath).Equals("login.aspx") || System.IO.Path.GetFileName(this.Page.Request.FilePath).Equals("login_error.aspx"))
               return base.PageStatePersister;
           string viewStateStorage = "memory";
           if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ViewStateStorage"] != null)
               viewStateStorage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ViewStateStorage"];               
           if (viewStateStorage != null && viewStateStorage.Equals("memory"))
           {
               return new CachePageStatePersister(Page);
           }
           if (viewStateStorage != null && viewStateStorage.Equals("session"))
           {
               return new SessionPageStatePersister(Page);
           }
           return base.PageStatePersister;
       }
   }
```

We are saving ViewState into memory, but when Session ends, ViewState is destroyed. Why?

Answer (score 2):

If you are saving the viewstate in memory, you are saving it in the Session. So when you session ends, your viewstate is also removed from memory.

Comment: So if I save CachePageStatePersister(Page) or SessionPageStatePersister(Page) it will be still saved in session?